# Adding source and target fields to attribute table

Tags: qgis, export, csv

I am trying to find a way to add source and target to a CSV file which is being exported to Gephi (network analysis software) for a edges (line) layer. However, when importing into Gephi I am missing the "source" and "target" fields in the CSV file.

The layer is a multistring where each intersection is the separation point for each line. I have already tried AequilibraE and Qchainage but both are barely supported and consistently give errors.

This is largely an effort to export the line layer as a GraphML file (instead of GML) by going through Gephi.

Comment: If you don't have the `source` and `target` fields, it means you have not created them...? Do I miss something? Probably you should add more information so we understand the problem. Are you asking how to create a new field in QGIS that can then be exported to CSV? Have a look at Field calculator then. Otherwise: did you check this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=gephi

Comment: The issue here is that the layer does not automatically have source and target fields. Thus I was wondering if there would be an automatic way of doing so.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? The software acting independently, without your intervention? Sorry, I struggle to understand your expectations. Are you asking about "how to automatically create a field `source` and `target` whenever I export a layer"? What kind of information should these fields contain? Please edit and revise your question to make clear A) what you have, B) what you've tried, C) where you're stuck and D)what you expect as result. See [tour] how to ask questions.